# Azure function host stops automatically and doesn't restart

Tags: azure, function, restart, azure-triggers

I've seen in multiple Azure function apps that the host is stopping on a regular basis and automatically restarting.
Since a week on of my Azure function apps is stopping, but I need to manually restart the host.

In ApplicationInsights a ran the following query:

```
traces 
| where message == "Job host stopped" or message == "Job host started"
| order by timestamp asc
```

[snippet from traces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nih3w.png)

- 23-1-2022 20:08:42.436    Job host started
- 23-1-2022 20:09:25.668    Job host stopped
- 23-1-2022 21:08:48.800    Job host started
- 23-1-2022 21:11:33.702    Job host stopped
- 23-1-2022 22:17:03.286    Job host stopped
- 23-1-2022 22:18:39.002    Job host started
- 23-1-2022 23:10:31.580    Job host stopped
- 24-1-2022 06:41:48.024    Job host started
- 24-1-2022 06:42:44.680    Job host stopped
- 24-1-2022 06:43:00.902    Job host started
- 24-1-2022 07:10:52.220    Job host stopped

The start on 24-1-2022 06:41 is due to a manual restart of my function app. No timetrigger has executed durring this stop period. This is happening more than once a day. Without a pattern.

Any ideas? eventlog isn't usefull, between the auto-stop and manual restart is nog logging in insights.

How can I trouble shoot this? Why is the function restarting so often?

Update: a manual trigger (http) is restarting the host.

Answer (score 0):

Good morning Johan.

If your host is permanently stopped:

> try checking app_offline.html file within your project.
>
> for more detailed info:
> https://www.codit.eu/blog/why-is-my-azure-function-host-permanently-stopped/

If  your question is related to that the host start and stop continuosly:

This kind of behaviour can be related to your plan, I think you have a consumption plan within you azure functions.

> **Consumption plan:**  On the Consumption plan, instances of the Functions host are dynamically added and removed based on the number
> of incoming events.
>
> **Premium plan:**  Your function apps run continuously, or nearly continuously.
>
> **Dedicated plan:** Run your functions within an App Service plan at regular App Service plan rates.
>
> For more info you can go to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale

Comment: Host is not permanently stopped, calling a manual HTTP-trigger is starting up the timetriggers again.
I have a consumption plan, but non of our function apps (we have a about 40 apps running) is having this behavior.